# emmeans using weights to account for sample size differences in one factor

Tags: r, emmeans

I'd like to obtain emmeans of a continuous response for each level of a several-level factor (numerous different populations) while "correcting" for differences in the frequency in another factor (gender) between the first, assuming no interaction between these two.

The model I am working with is `x <- lm(response ~ size*population + gender)`.

As I understand it, `weights=equal` and `weights=proportional` do not take into account differences in the frequency of the gender factor across different populations, but use either an equal frequency or the frequency in the entire sample, respectively. The description of `weights=outer` is rather obscure to me, but it doesn't sound like this is exactly what I'm looking for either; the emmeans package documentation states: "All except "cells" uses the same set of weights for each mean."

But it seems like `weights=cells` is also not what I'm looking for, as it the emmeans will be closer to the ordinary marginal means, whereas I want them to be further away in cases where gender is unbalanced in certain populations. If I understand correctly, I would like the weighting to be the 'reverse' of this option. The emmean for each population should reflect what the mean of each population *should* be if gender had been sampled equally in each.

Perhaps I don't understand these weights fully, but is there an option to set weights to accomplish this?

Comment: You should edit this question to have data and code to which we can apply comments and possible solution. Otherwise it is too vague.

Comment: Might I suggest `emtrends()` instead of `emmeans()`? It estimates the *slope* of the `size‘ trend. And I suggest either equal or proportional weighting if you compute marginals over gender.